# CS50 coding exercise Mario less comfortable

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to any programming and new to computer science in general. This exercise was a real headache for me and I spent maybe two days reading stuff and trying to find how to write a solution for it.
I used a lot of information I found everywhere to make my "own" code. It's not mine really.

Now with all this job that I've done I still don't get why do I get one extra space printed at the beginning of every row. When there is let's say 5 rows and the height is 5 there is one extra space at the beginning. Could anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong, please? Thank you

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 9);

    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
    {
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (int k = 1; k <= height - row; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? What is it doing instead? Please be more precise on the problem.

Comment: It would help to know what the program you wrote is supposed to do. If the problem is just that there's an extra space on every line then maybe remove the extra printf(" "); in the start of your loop?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it  better. The whole idea is to build a code that gives the output that looks like a pyramid of #.

Comment: The first `printf` inside the for loop prints a space unconditionally.

Comment: Which style of pyramid do you want :Half pyramid or Inverted half of pyramid Full pyramid or Inverted full ?

Comment: Hell. I tried it and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot for it. It was so simple and yet so hard for me to get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's trace you for loop

```
    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
    {
        // print space at first of row
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        // print space as how many rows left
        for (int k = 1; k <= height - row; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        // print # for each row
        for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        // new line
            printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It was so obvious but not to me. Now I get it

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 `for` loops.

Inside the outermost loop, there are two `for` loops. Your code first prints a space, and then runs the two inner `for` loops.

The second `for` loop also prints a space.
The third `for` loop prints a number of `#` characters depending on the height of the tower.

If you're asking why there's an extra space, it's that first statement in the `for` loop.

I'm no C expert but i believe the braces are unnecessary. Remove that and your code should not have extra spaces.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 9);

    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= height - row; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int height=10;
   for (int i= 1; i <= height; i++)
   {
      for(int j=height-1;j>=i;j--)
      {
          printf(" ");//print a space : ' '
      }
      for(int k=1;k<=i;k++)
      {
         printf("#");//print this caracter :'#'
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me your code. I've tried it and it seems like it executes it straight away without user input on how many # and rows of them to print. It's interesting to see the differences and that way I'll learn.

Comment: @Russ:You're welcome, please make this answer useful